# Did Picard know who Guinan was when he took command of the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

The events of "Time's Arrow" clearly indicate that Guinan knows who Picard is when he takes command of the *Enterprise*.  But is the converse true: does *Picard* know who *Guinan* is at that time?

[What is Guinan and Picard’s history?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56237) is related, but has several conflicting answers, some of which also conflict with other episodes of the series, and therefore does not adequately answer this specific question.

Comment: Sorry, but the answers on the other question cover this in considerable depth, including a quote from Guinan about him not knowing her until she came aboard the Enterprise and conflicting quotes from various EU sources. If you don't feel that the answers are sufficient to deal with this *aspect* of their relationship, I'd strongly suggest you post a bounty with the reason "***Improve Details***".